# Matrix multiplication(dynamic memory allocation) in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to perform matrix multiplication using dynamic memory allocation in C programming where i am taking user input for the number of rows and columns for each matrix. The output is correct when r1=c2(mat1 r1xc1 and mat2 r2xc2) but mat 4x2 and mat 2x3 is giving segmentation fault. Kindly advise.
The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void create(int **arr,int r,int c)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*c);

        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            scanf("%d",*(arr+i)+j);
    }
}

void display(int **arr,int r,int c)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            printf("%d    ",*(*(arr+i)+j));

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void multiply(int **arr1,int **arr2,int **arr3,int r,int c1,int c2)
{
    int i,j,k;

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
        {
            arr3[i][j]=0;

            for(k=0;k<c1;k++)
                *(*(arr3+i)+j) += *(*(arr1+i)+k) * *(*(arr2+k)+j);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int **arr1,r1,c1,**arr2,r2,c2,**arr3;

    printf("Enter rows and columns of first matrix: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&r1,&c1);

    arr1=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*r1*c1);
    printf("\nEnter elements of first matrix: ");
    
    create(arr1,r1,c1); 

    printf("\nThe first matrix is: \n");

    display(arr1,r1,c1);

    printf("\nEnter rows and columns of second matrix: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&r2,&c2);

    arr2=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*r2*c2);
    printf("\nEnter elements of second matrix: ");
    
    create(arr2,r2,c2); 

    printf("\nThe second matrix is: \n");

    display(arr2,r2,c2);

    if(c1!=r2)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid dimensions.");
        exit(0);
    }

    arr3=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*r1*c2);

    printf("\nThe product is: \n");

    multiply(arr1,arr2,arr3,r1,c1,c2);

    display(arr3,r1,c2);

    free(arr1);
    free(arr2);
    free(arr3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the specific input you're using that causes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why you are getting a segmentation fault is that you did not allocate the matrix rows for the resulting matrix *arr3*. Further bugs in your code indicate that you haven't fully understood the memory organization of matrices.

You have chosen a so called *row-major* array of arrays. That's a solid choice. In memory, it looks like so (for a 3 by 4 matrix):

[image: Row-major array of arrays]

Each row is allocated separately (as an array of numbers). These are the horizontal bars.

The rows are held together by the vertical bar, an array of arrays. In C, it's basically an array of pointers.

Finally, you have a variable holding the reference to the vertical bar (called *arr* in the figure). It's the variable used to represent the matrix.

As is now obvious that multiple memory allocations are needed for each matrix, one for the vertical bar and multiple ones for the rows. The vertical bars are allocate in your `main()` function, the rows are allocated in the `create()` function. But `create()` is not called for `arr3`. So it results in a segmentation fault.

There are further problems in your code:

- The memory allocation for vertical bar is way too big. The array only needs to be of size *r*, not of size *r* * *c* (*r* and *c* being the number of rows and columns).
- The arrays for the rows are never freed.

I would also recommend to use array notation for accessing the matrix elements instead of pointer arithmetic. Thus, instead of:

```
*(*(arr1+i)+k)
```

you could use:

```
arr1[i][k]
```

The reason it has work for small matrices is luck. It has likely overwritten some other data, which usually causes a crash.